# How to specify date format (DateType) when defining pyspark schema?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dataframe, pyspark

I have a python application which parses a document into a dictionary format(JSON) with time information in it, among multiple other things. The document has a string with this time '%Y-%m-%d%H.%M.%S' format which I convert into a datetime object with the strptime function.

All the information is then converted to a PySpark DataFrame in order to save it a MongoDb collection.

The problem is, when I convert the dictionaries into the DataFrame I lose the hours, minutes and seconds information and end up saving just '2020-05-29 00:00:00.000z' to the Mongo collection, but I need the hh,mm and ss in oder to filter later on. What might be happening?

This is what I'm doing:

For the Date:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                    date.decode('utf-8'), '%Y-%m-%d%H.%M.%S')
```

Each dictionary item goes something like this and are stored in a list called records:

```
{'name': 'Contrato', 'fecha': date, 'origin': 'input'}
```

The schema I created for the Dataframe:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('fecha', DateType(), True),
    StructField('origin', BooleanType(), True)
])
```

and then I call:

```
spark.createDataFrame(records, schema)
```

When I print the DF I get this:

[image: df.show]

And when I load it to Mongo it always shows is without the hours, minutes or seconds:

[image: MongoDB date record]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add some examples of your initial date strings? The DateType() only holds the date by the way.

Comment: @cronoik Fixed it by changing it to TimestampType(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the DateType() to TimestampType(). It works perfectly now!

```
schema = StructType([
StructField('name', StringType(), True),
StructField('fecha', TimestampType(), True),
StructField('origin', BooleanType(), True)
])
```